# Jquery form creation not submitting in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm hosting a simple test page at http://ss.amityregion5.org/crypto.php.

It's simply testing RSA encryption: Client Jquery, upon hitting the submit button, encrypts the message with the server's public key (visible in javascript). This encrypted value is sent to the server, which decrypts the message with its own private key.

This code runs perfectly fine in Chrome and Safari. However in Internet Explorer (11), the form fails to submit. Interestingly, however, the Developer Console never spits out an error, so I'm at a loss as to what the issue is. I may just be missing something stupid, or IE could be doing something funky with JS parsing.

From my incremental testing, I suspect the issue might be the last line of my javascript, where I create a hidden form element, fill it with the ciphertext, and submit it. Is this behavior not supported on I.E., and if not, how may I fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append the form to the document before you submit it.

```
$('<form method="post"><input type="hidden" name="message" value="' + ciphertext + '"></form>')
    .appendTo("body")
    .submit();
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. Firefox/IE web engine must not like parsing non-appended elements.